# How to get Id of public key without importing private key?

Tags: gnupg, pgp, keychain

If I run the following on a private key to install it in my keyserver:

```
gpg --allow-secret-key-import --import my_private.key
```

It will import an associated public key presumably from a keyserver?

```
gpg: key xyz...: public key "example@example.com" imported
```

My question is: How can I find out the ID of this public key without having to install the private key to my keychain?

Comment: That imports to your keyring and/or agent, depending on gpg version; no keyserver is involved. PGP privatekey format includes the corresponding publickey and the displayed publickey info is obtained from the privatekey; no keyserver is involved. The answer how to display a privatekey is the same as [your previous Q about displaying a publickey](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/170117/how-do-i-check-who-a-public-pgp-rsa-key-belongs-to)

Answer (score 5):

Given the following public key in Privacy Enhanced Mail (Base64 encoded DER) format:

```
$ wget https://apt.dockerproject.org/gpg -O dockerproject.gpg.pub.key
$ cat dockerproject.gpg.pub.key
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
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=Fm3p
-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

The following commands will all show the long key id without adding it to your keyring:

```
$ gpg --list-packets dockerproject.gpg.pub.key | \
awk '/keyid:/{ print $2 }'
F76221572C52609D
$ gpg --with-colons dockerproject.gpg.pub.key 2>&1 | \
awk -F':' '/pub/{ print $5 }'
F76221572C52609D
$ gpg --dry-run --verbose --import dockerproject.gpg.pub.key 2>&1 | \
awk '/pub/{ print $3 }' | awk -F'/' '{ print $2 }'
F76221572C52609D
$ gpg --with-fingerprint --verbose dockerproject.gpg.pub.key 2>&1 | \
awk '/^sig/{ print $2 }'
F76221572C52609D
```

When using this version of `gpg`:

```
$ gpg --version | head -n 1
gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4
```

These commands are not very friendly or intuitive and spit out confusing messages like `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...` on STDERR. They also seem to often be subtly different between versions, for example  my version sometimes requires `--verbose` compared to some answers out there. This version does not have the `--show-keys` flag which looks easier than most of the commands above.

Some useful information about key ids:

- Key ID Short Format: `2C52609D`
- Key ID Long Format: `F76221572C52609D`
- Key Signature: `58118E89F3A912897C070ADBF76221572C52609D`

You should use long format as the short format [is insecure](https://gwolf.org/node/4070)

Comment: This works with GPG 1.4.16, but it doesn't work with GPG 2.1.18.

Answer (score 4):

Just call the `gpg` command line tool and pass it the keyfile as an option

```
$ gpg my_private.key
sec  4096R/1234ABCD 2017-09-12 foo@bar.com
```

The long version (without warning "gpg: WARNING: no command supplied. ..." - since gnupg-version >= 2.1.23 - found this [here](https://www.iditect.com/how-to/56283822.html)):

```
gpg --import-options show-only --import my_private.key
```

Comment: Annoyingly, it also prints `gpg: WARNING: no command supplied.  Trying to guess what you mean ...`. I would prefer knowing the actual command, both to remove ambiguity and the warning.

Comment: Interesting. I do not get the warning on my machine (Ubuntu Xenial). It also shouldn't be a problem according to the man page: *gpg may be run with no commands, in which case it will perform a reasonable action depending on the type of file it is given  as
       input (an encrypted message is decrypted, a signature is verified, a file containing keys is listed)*

Comment: This works with GPG 1.4.16, but it doesn't work with GPG 2.1.18.

Comment: I found here (https://www.iditect.com/how-to/56283822.html) how to GET RID OF THE WARNING: "Since GnuPG 2.1.23, the gpg: WARNING: no command supplied. Trying to guess what you mean ... warning can be omitted by using the --import-options show-only option together with the --import command" so the 'simple' command to just get information about a file without an error would be: `gpg --import-options show-only --import my_keyfile.key`

Answer (score 4):

To get the key IDs (8 bytes, 16 hex digits), this is the command which worked for me in GPG 1.4.16, 2.1.18 and 2.2.19:

```
gpg --list-packets <key.asc | awk '$1=="keyid:"{print$2}'
```

To get some more information (in addition to the key ID):

```
gpg --list-packets <key.asc
```

To get even more information:

```
gpg --list-packets -vvv --debug 0x2 <key.asc
```

The command

```
gpg --dry-run --import <key.asc
```

also works in all 3 versions, but in GPG 1.4.16 it prints only a short (4 bytes, 8 hex digits) key ID, so it's less secure to identify keys.

Commands in other answers (e.g. `gpg --show-keys`, `gpg --with-fingerprint`, `gpg --import --import-options show-only`) don't work in some of the 3 GPG versions above, thus they are not portable when targeting multiple versions of GPG.

Comment: Wow! Last post is the one that did it. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you refer to a PGP key then this may be the answer.

From the gpg manual (gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.11):

> --show-keys
>
> This commands takes OpenPGP keys as input and prints information about  them in  the  same  way  the command --list-keys does for locally stored key.  In addition the list options show-unusable-uids,  show-unusable-subkeys,  show-notations  and  show-policy-urls  are  also enabled.  As usual for automated processing, this command should be combined with the option --with-colons.

For instance:

`$ gpg --show-keys docker-ce.gpg
pub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [SCEA]
      9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88
uid                      Docker Release (CE deb) <docker@docker.com>
sub   rsa4096 2017-02-22 [S]`

where 9DC858229FC7DD38854AE2D88D81803C0EBFCD88 is the key id.

Comment: This doesn't work with GPG 1.4.16 or GPG 2.1.18.